# Embed text files into Visual C++ 2012 CLR

Tags: visual-c++, embed

I have a CLR in C++. At runtime, It shows the content stored as TXT file in the working directory with I/O functions.

I have problems to distribute my program (EXE) because people normally forget to move the text files together with the Application.

How can I embed this TXT file into the application and distribute only one file (EXE)

Thanks.

Comment: *Resources*; http://fczaja.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/visual-studio-adding-and-using-resource.html

Comment: It seems I have some problems using the method in your source link. I still can not embed the TXT.